# gitignore does not work for db-files

Tags: git, grails

I am working with grails and generated my .gitignore file by

```
integrate-with --git
```

the gitignore contains a line

```
    /*DB.*
```

that should omit the top level databasefile

```
   prodDb.h2.db
```

from commiting but it does not. I already tried the line

```
   /*Db.*
```

but that doesn't work either.

peter

Comment: `/*Db.*` works fine on unix with git 2.0.  what version are you using and what OS?

Comment: Is the `prodDb.h2.db` file already being tracked? Git's ignore system only applies to untracked files.

Answer (score 9):

I guess the file is already tracked, so just delete it:

```
$ git rm prodDb.h2.db
$ git commit -m "Remove database file"
```

Then put this at your `.gitignore`:

```
*Db.*
```

Comment: with git rm prodDb.h2.db I get fatal: Pfadspezifikation 'prodDb.h2.db' stimmt mit keinen Dateien überein
in english: fatal: pathSpecification 'prodDb.h2.db' does not match with any data sets